# Best way to link a table to 2 different keys?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm designing a mySQL DB and I'm having the following issue:

Say I have a wall_posts table. Walls can belong to either an event or a user.
Hence the `wall_posts` table must references either `event_id` or `user_id` (foreign key constraint).

What is the best way to build such a relationship, considering I must always be able to know who the walls belong to ... ?

I've been considering using 2 tables, such as `event_wall_posts` and `user_wall_posts` so one got an `event_id` field and the other a `user_id` one, but I believe there must be something much better than such a redundant workaround ...

Is there a way to use an intermediate table to link the `wall_posts` to either an `event_id` or a `user_id` ?

Thanks in advance,

Edit : seems there is not a clear design to do this and both approach seem okay, so,
which one will be the fastest if there is a lots of data ?

Is it preferable to have 2 separates table (so queries might be faster, since there will be twice less data in tables ...), or is it still preferable to have a better OO approach with a single `wall_posts` table referencing a wall table (and then both users and `events will have a unique`wall_id`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called an **exclusive arc** and it's not a good practice. It's hard to enforce referential integrity. You're probably better off using, in an object sense, a common supertype.

That can be modelled in a couple of ways:

1. A supertype table called, say, wall. Two subtype tables (user_wall and event_wall) that link to a user and event respectively as the owner. The wall_posts table links to the supertype table; or
2. Putting both entity types into one table and having a type column. That way you're not linking to two separate tables.

Answer (score 4):

Why is it redundant? You won't write code twice to handle them, you will use the same code, just change the name of the table in the SQL.
Another reason to take this approach is that some time in the future you will discover you need new **different** fields for each entity.

Comment: Totally agree - there's no reason to cram everything into as few tables as possible, and every reason to have multiple tables in this instance so you can implement referential integrity.

Comment: I'm thinking it's redundant because I got twice the same table structures, with the exception of one different FK for each ... that's actually how I prototyped the application, with one model for both table as you said, but I keep thinking there's something wrong :/

Comment: Remember tables are not code per-Se. Different entities (even if they look the same today) should be stored in different places. I have run into the same problem many times and got burned when I took the approach of one table.

Answer (score 2):

Go for the simplest solution: add both an event_id and a user_id column to the wall_posts table.  Use constraints to enforce that one of them is null, and the other is not.

Anything more complex smells like overnormalization to me :)

Answer (score 1):

A classical approach to this problem is:

- Create a table called `wall_container` and keep properties common to both `users` and `events` in it
- Reference both `users` and `events` to `wall_container`
- Reference `wall_posts` to `wall_container`

However, this is not very efficient and it's not guaranteed that this `wall_container` doesn't containt records that are not either a `user` or an `event`.

`SQL` is not particularly good in handling multiple inheritance.

Comment: SQL doesn't even support inheritance since SQL is data-driven, not object-oriented. Then again, this is of course why you need a good data layer on top of your database, which will implement a base class for wall_container and two inherited classes events and users. These classes then need to contain the logic to avoid any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Your wall and event has their own unique IDs .. right?? then their is no need for another table . let the wall_post table have a attribute as origin which will direct to the record of whatever the record is event's or users. '

If the wall and event may have same ID then make a table with three attributes origin(primary), ID number and type. There ID number will be what you set, type defining what kind of entity does the ID represent and origin will be a new ID which you will generate maybe adding different prefix. In case of same ID the origin table will help you immensely for other things to other than wall posts.